# Automate running Cisco VPN Client and RDP

Tags: vpn, cisco, remote-desktop, powershell, batch-file

I am trying to automate running the Cisco VPN Client and then a RDP session.

What is a good way to do this?
Batch File?
Powershell?
Other

I have played with a batch file and this kind of works.

```
cmd.exe /c "C:\Program Files\Cisco Systems\VPN Client\vpngui.exe"
cmd.exe /c "N:\Data\Gerhard\BeneSys\VPN, RDP\bene00226t_gweiss.rdp"
```

But it does not get past running the vpn client.

I am using
Windows 7 RC
Cisco VPN Client 5.0.01.0600
Windows Remote Desktop Connection

Answer (score 3):

Open the VPN client.  Click on Options then Application Launcher.  Click the Enable check box and select the app to run.  After the VPN connects the Cisco software will then run the app specified.

Comment: Thanks for having me look at the Cisco VPN Cliet. I also found checking "Enable connect on open" under Options|Preferences very useful because I only have one connection entry. Now I do not have to click the connect button.

Comment: Application Launcher sounds like a fantastic idea but I am not able to get it to run. Maybe this is a bug with W7 RC and my version of the VPN Client? I am going to look into upgrading my VPN Client to the latest version.

Comment: While Cisco version are you using?  I've got 5.0.05.0280 (a beta) and it worked fine on Windows 7 RC.  Also in the preferences check the "Hide on Connect" so that the window closes to the system tray after it connects to you don't have to look at it all day for no reason.

Answer (score 0):

I found a really cool (FREE!) application that allows you to do this:  check out http://remotedesktopmanager.com/.  It creates oodles of session types RDP, VNC, FTP, SSH, ICA, and several more.  Supports multiple monitors, import and export of connections.  I've convinced everyone at my office to switch to this software.  Oh and you can attach your Cisco VPN to individual connections to allow easy in-office/out-of-office connections.